# Is there a list of the blocking system calls in Linux?

Tags: linux, call, system

What are all of the blocking system calls in Linux?  I'm looking for the set of system calls where the calling process can/will be suspended and put in a wait-queue until the system call completes.

For example, poll(2) is a blocking system call as indicated in its manual entry:

```
  If  none of the events requested (and no error) has occurred
  for any of the file descriptors, then  poll() blocks until
  one of the events occurs.
```

However, most manual entries for system calls do not state explicitly whether or not the system call can or will block.  For example, is mprotect(2) a blocking system call?